# No body data found in Laravel 5.3 with PUT request

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Here is my route to update the contacts.

```
Route::put( 'contact-type/{id}', 'ContactTypeController@update' );
```

Here is the controller to test if the request was there with the PUT request.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return response()->json([ 'id' => $id, 'req' => $request->all() ]);
}
```

When i send a request using postman, the request is null!

[image]

Is the body payload is not allowed in laravel PUT requests? Or how we send additional data in a PUT request?

Comment: What header have you got set up?

Comment: @RossWilson i have only one Authorization header with bearer token.

Comment: Just got the same problem. Why form-date works for POST request but not in PUT/PATCH request. Is this intended behavior or just a bug on Postman?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just change from `form-data` to `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

[image: Postman body options]

Comment: I changed and start getting request in controller , but now I cant upload file

Answer (score 13):

[image]If you had to use **form-data** (to upload images) as file input doesn't exists in **x-www-form-urlencode**

you can send a **POST**-Request and add a field with the name  **_method** and the value PUT or PATCH to the request body.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I could not quite understand your answer

Comment: @Adelin I've just updated the answer with a  screenshot , hope this helps

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer, especially if you need to upload the file(s) as well

Comment: [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686218/laravel-vuejs-axios-put-request-formdata-is-empty) on laravel does not handle multipart-formdata well with PUT method. Sending a POST request to a backend laravel PUT route works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate `Content-Type` header for your data.

Click `x-www-form-control` this should add the appropriate header.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

you are passing form-data instead you need to check x-www-form-urlencoded in post-man.