# laravel vuejs/axios put request Formdata is empty

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a few application, when I am sending formdata using axios post data is successfully sent to API. but when i am using put request its not working with formData.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background:#fff">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h4 class="page-title">
          <i class="flaticon-users"></i> Leads
        </h4>
        <ul class="breadcrumbs">
          <li class="nav-home">
            <a href="/">
              <i class="flaticon-home"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="separator">
            <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/leads">Leads</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="separator">
            <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <template>
        <div class="btn-wrapper">
          <button v-on:click="seen = !seen" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
            <i class="flaticon-interface-1"></i>Add New Lead
          </button>
        </div>
        <p></p>
      </template>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" v-if="!seen">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="card-title">
                <i class="flaticon-interface-1"></i> New Leads
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form
                @submit.prevent="addLeads"
                id="leadform"
                class="mb-3"
                enctype="multipart/form-data"
              >
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>Lead</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          id="name"
                          name="lead_name"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Lead Name"
                          v-model="form.name"
                        >
                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'name'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>Source</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea
                          type="text"
                          id="source"
                          name="source"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="lead Souve"
                          v-model="form.source"
                        ></textarea>

                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'source'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>Value</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          id="value"
                          name="value"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="lead Value"
                          v-model="form.value"
                        >

                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'value'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>Notes</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea
                          type="text"
                          id="notes"
                          name="notes"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="lead Notes"
                          v-model="form.notes"
                        ></textarea>

                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'notes'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Assigned To</label>
                        <template v-if="!userlist">
                          <select class="form-control" id="assigned_to">
                            <option value>No User Found</option>
                          </select>
                        </template>
                        <template v-else>
                          <select
                            v-model="form.assigned_to"
                            name="assigned_to"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="assigned_to"
                          >
                            <option value>Please Select</option>
                            <option v-for="user in userlist" :key="user.id" :value="user.id">
                              <template v-if="user.id == currentUser.id">Me</template>
                              <template v-else>{{ user.name }}</template>
                            </option>
                          </select>
                        </template>
                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'assigned_to'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Close Date</label>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <date-picker v-model="form.date" name="close_date"></date-picker>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>Email</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          id="email"
                          name="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="User Email"
                          v-model="form.email"
                        >

                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'email'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label>Phone</label>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          id="phone"
                          name="phone"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="User Phone Number"
                          v-model="form.phone"
                        >

                        <template v-if="errors">
                          <span v-for="(fieldsError, fieldName) in errors" :key="fieldName">
                            <template v-if="fieldName == 'phone'">
                              <p class="errors">
                                <strong>{{ fieldsError.join('\n') }}</strong>
                              </p>
                            </template>
                          </span>
                        </template>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input
                        type="file"
                        multiple="multiple"
                        id="attachments"
                        @change="uploadFieldChange"
                      >
                      <hr>
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div
                          class="attachment-holder animated fadeIn"
                          v-cloak
                          v-for="(attachment, index) in attachments"
                        >
                          <template v-if="attachment.file_name">
                            <span class="label label-primary">{{ attachment.file_name}}</span>
                          </template>
                          <template v-else>
                            <span
                              class="label label-primary"
                            >{{ attachment.name + ' (' + Number((attachment.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(1)) + 'MB)'}}</span>
                          </template>
                          <span
                            class
                            style="background: red; cursor: pointer;"
                            @click="removeAttachment(attachment)"
                          >
                            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remove</button>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <label>Status</label>
                      <br>
                      <label class="form-radio-label">
                        <input
                          class="form-radio-input"
                          v-model="form.status"
                          type="radio"
                          name="status"
                          value="open"
                          checked
                        >
                        <span class="form-radio-sign">Open</span>
                      </label>
                      <label class="form-radio-label ml-3">
                        <input
                          class="form-radio-input"
                          v-model="form.status"
                          type="radio"
                          name="status"
                          value="sent"
                        >
                        <span class="form-radio-sign">Proposal Sent</span>
                      </label>
                      <label class="form-radio-label ml-3">
                        <input
                          class="form-radio-input"
                          v-model="form.status"
                          type="radio"
                          name="status"
                          value="won"
                        >
                        <span class="form-radio-sign">Won</span>
                      </label>
                      <label class="form-radio-label ml-3">
                        <input
                          class="form-radio-input"
                          v-model="form.status"
                          type="radio"
                          name="status"
                          value="lost"
                        >
                        <span class="form-radio-sign">lost</span>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    <button @click="clearForm()" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background:#fff;">
      <kanban-board :stages="stages" :blocks="blocks" @update-block="updateBlock">
        <div v-for="stage in stages" :slot="stage">
          <h2>{{ stage }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div v-for="block in blocks" :slot="block.id">
          <div>
            <strong>{{ block.name }}</strong>
          </div>
          <p></p>
          <button class="btn btn-danger">UKDH</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning">£ {{ block.value }}</button>
          <router-link :to="`/account/${block.id}/convert`" class="btn btn-primary">create account</router-link>
          <div class="text-right">
            <router-link :to="`/leads/${block.id}`" class="btn btn-link btn-info">
              <i class="la la-street-view"></i>
            </router-link>

            <a href="#" @click="deleteLead(block.id)" class="btn btn-link btn-danger">
              <i class="la la-times"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" @click="editLead(block)" class="btn btn-link btn-primary">
              <i class="la la-edit"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </kanban-board>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { addLeadsAPI } from "../../helpers/api";
import { updateStatus } from "../../helpers/api";
import { getCommonAPI } from "../../helpers/api";
import { deleteAPI } from "../../helpers/api";
import validate from "validate.js";
import DatePicker from "vue2-datepicker";

export default {
  name: "leads",
  components: {
    DatePicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      leads: [],
      userlist: [],
      attachments: [],
      percentCompleted: 0,
      upload_size: 0,
      result: {},
      stages: ["open", "sent", "lost", "won"],
      blocks: [],
      form: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        source: "",
        value: 0,
        notes: "",
        user_id: "",
        assigned_to: 1,
        date: new Date(),
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        status: ""
      },
      lead_id: "",
      pagination: {},
      edit: false,
      isOpen: 0,
      seen: true,
      errors: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchLeads();
    this.getusers();
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("leads");
  },
  methods: {
    getusers(page_url) {
      let vm = this;
      getCommonAPI("/users", "get", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.currentUser.token}`,
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }).then(res => {
        vm.userlist = res.data;
      });
    },

    fetchLeads(page_url) {
      let vm = this;
      page_url = page_url || "/leads/lead";
      getCommonAPI(page_url, "get", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.currentUser.token}`,
          Accept: "application/json"
        }
      }).then(res => {
        vm.blocks = res.data.data;
        //vm.makePagination(res.meta, res.links);
      });
    },
    makePagination(meta, links) {
      let pagination = {
        current_page: meta.current_page,
        last_page: meta.last_page,
        next_page_url: links.next,
        prev_page_url: links.prev
      };
      this.pagination = pagination;
    },
    editLead(form) {
      console.log(form);
      this.edit = true;
      this.seen = false;
      this.form.id = form.id;
      this.form.name = form.name;
      this.form.lead_sid = form.lead_sid;
      this.form.status = form.status;
      this.form.type = form.type;
      this.form.source = form.source;
      this.form.value = form.value;
      this.form.notes = form.notes;
      this.form.email = form.email;
      this.form.phone = form.phone;
      this.form.assigned_to = form.assigned_to;
      this.form.date = form.close_date;
      this.attachments = form.uploads;
    },
    clearForm() {
      this.edit = false;
      this.form.id = null;
      this.form.user_id = null;
      this.form.assigned_to = "";
      this.form.type = "";
      this.form.status = true;
      this.form.name = "";
      this.form.source = "";
      this.form.value = "";
      this.form.notes = "";
      this.form.email = "";
      this.form.phone = "";
      this.attachments = [];
    },
    addLeads() {
      if (this.edit === false) {
        // add new leads
        this.errors = null;
        const constraints = this.getConstraints();
        const errors = validate(this.$data.form, constraints);
        if (errors) {
          this.errors = errors;
          return;
        }
        // multiple file uploading
        this.lead = document.getElementById("leadform");
        const formData = new FormData(this.lead);
        if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
            let attachment = this.attachments[i];
            formData.append("attachments[]", attachment);
          }
        }
        var config = {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            this.percentCompleted = Math.round(
              (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
            );
            this.$forceUpdate();
          }.bind(this)
        };
        //end
        this.$store.dispatch("lead");

        addLeadsAPI(formData, "post").then(res => {
          swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
          this.clearForm();
          this.fetchLeads();
          //this.attachments = [];
        });
      } else {
        this.errors = null;

        const constraints = this.getConstraints();
        const errors = validate(this.$data.form, constraints);
        if (errors) {
          this.errors = errors;
          return;
        }
        console.log("i am in edit");
        // multiple file uploading
        this.lead = document.getElementById("leadform");
        let formData = new FormData(this.lead);
        if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
            let attachment = this.attachments[i];
            formData.append("attachments[]", attachment);
          }
        }
        console.log(formData);
        var config = {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            this.percentCompleted = Math.round(
              (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
            );
            this.$forceUpdate();
          }.bind(this)
        };
        //end
        console.log(formData);
        this.$store.dispatch("lead");
        //update
        addLeadsAPI(formData, "put").then(res => {
          swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
          this.clearForm();
          this.fetchLeads();
          //this.attachments = [];
        });
      }
    },
    getConstraints() {
      return {
        name: {
          presence: true,
          length: {
            minimum: 6,
            message: "Must be at least 6 characters long"
          }
        },
        source: {
          presence: true,
          length: {
            minimum: 6,
            message: "Must be at least 6 characters long"
          }
        },
        value: {
          presence: true,
          length: {
            minimum: 1,
            message: "Must be at least 1 characters long"
          }
        },
        notes: {
          presence: true,
          length: {
            minimum: 6,
            message: "Must be at least 6 characters long"
          }
        }
      };
    },
    updateBlock(id, status) {
      //api call axios
      updateStatus(id, status, "get").then(res => {
        this.clearForm();
        this.fetchLeads();
      });
      this.blocks.find(b => b.id === Number(id)).status = status;
    },
    deleteLead(id) {
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Do you really want to delete Lead!",
        type: "warning",
        buttons: {
          confirm: {
            text: "Yes, delete it!",
            className: "btn btn-success"
          },
          cancel: {
            visible: true,
            className: "btn btn-danger"
          }
        }
      }).then(Delete => {
        if (Delete) {
          deleteAPI(`/lead/${id}`, "delete", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.currentUser.token}`,
              Accept: "application/json"
            }
          }).then(res => {
            swal({
              title: "Deleted!",
              text: "Your lead has been deleted.",
              type: "success",
              buttons: {
                confirm: {
                  className: "btn btn-success"
                }
              }
            });
            this.fetchLeads();
          });
        } else {
          this.fetchLeads();
          swal.close();
        }
      });
    },
    getAttachmentSize() {
      this.upload_size = 0; // Reset to beginningƒ
      this.attachments.map(item => {
        this.upload_size += parseInt(item.size);
      });

      this.upload_size = Number(this.upload_size.toFixed(1));
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },

    removeAttachment(attachment) {
      this.attachments.splice(this.attachments.indexOf(attachment), 1);

      this.getAttachmentSize();
    },
    // This function will be called every time you add a file
    uploadFieldChange(e) {
      console.log(this.attachments);
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) return;
      for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.attachments.push(files[i]);
      }
      console.log("out");
      // Reset the form to avoid copying these files multiple times into this.attachments
      document.getElementById("attachments").value = [];
    }
  },
  computed: {
    users() {
      return this.$store.getters.users;
    },

    currentUser() {
      return this.$store.getters.currentUser;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style lang="scss">
@import "../assets/board.scss";
</style>
<style scoped>
.vue-js-switch#changed-font {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.errors {
  color: lightcoral;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 21px 0 2px 0;
}
</style>
```

when `edit` option true. I am calling method `addLeadsAPI` for posting data with `axios put` but Formdata is empty `$request->all()`.

Anyone can help me with this?seems `axios put` is not working for editing data. through formdata.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535510/put-form-data-axios-vue-js/65382178#65382178

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have changed the `axioscall` into post and set the value `_method:put`

```
addLeads() {
      if (this.edit === false) {
        // add new leads
        this.errors = null;
        const constraints = this.getConstraints();
        const errors = validate(this.$data.form, constraints);
        if (errors) {
          this.errors = errors;
          return;
        }
        // multiple file uploading
        this.lead = document.getElementById("leadform");
        const formData = new FormData(this.lead);
        if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
            let attachment = this.attachments[i];
            formData.append("attachments[]", attachment);
          }
        }
        var config = {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            this.percentCompleted = Math.round(
              (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
            );
            this.$forceUpdate();
          }.bind(this)
        };
        //end
        this.$store.dispatch("lead");
        formData.append("_method", "post");
        addLeadsAPI(formData, "post", config).then(res => {
          swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
          this.clearForm();
          this.fetchLeads();
          //this.attachments = [];
        });
      } else {
        this.errors = null;

        const constraints = this.getConstraints();
        const errors = validate(this.$data.form, constraints);
        if (errors) {
          this.errors = errors;
          return;
        }
        console.log("i am in edit");
        // multiple file uploading
        this.lead = document.getElementById("leadform");
        let formData = new FormData(this.lead);
        if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
            let attachment = this.attachments[i];
            formData.append("attachments[]", attachment);
          }
        }
        formData.append("_method", "put");
        formData.append("id", this.form.id);
        console.log(formData);
        var config = {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
          onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            this.percentCompleted = Math.round(
              (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
            );
            this.$forceUpdate();
          }.bind(this)
        };
        //end
        console.log(formData);
        this.$store.dispatch("lead");
        //update
        addLeadsAPI(formData, "put", config).then(res => {
          swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
          this.clearForm();
          this.fetchLeads();
          //this.attachments = [];
        });
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 25):

Laravel can not handle multipart-formdata well with PUT method. See [Input from PUT requests sent as multipart/form-data is unavailable #13457](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457).

If your code actually uses the PUT method, it seems to be affected by this problem.

There are several workarounds.

Dealing with the client side:

- Instead of PUT method, use POST method with `_method` parameter value set to `PUT` (called 'method spoofing')

Dealing with the server side:

- Add a package that performs multipart processing to Laravel. (ex. [illuminatech/multipart-middleware](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminatech/multipart-middleware))
- Use [pecl/apfd](https://pecl.php.net/package/apfd) extension which provides ability to parse 'multipart/form-data' HTTP requests for any request method.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed that by using post method instead of put.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I had an issue trying to update records using `axios` & `vue.js`.

**The solution** is to set the method value on the `formData` to `put`and send the request using the `post` method. Something like this:

```
console.log("i am in edit");
    // multiple file uploading
    this.lead = document.getElementById("leadform");
    let formData = new FormData(this.lead);
    if (this.attachments.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
        let attachment = this.attachments[i];
        formData.append("attachments[]", attachment);
      }
    }
    formData.append("_method", "put");
    console.log(formData);
```

In your axios request:

```
axios({
        method: "POST", // this is important
        url: {$your_destination_url},
        data: formData,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
    })
        .then(r => console.log(r.data))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this, https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing.
when using PUT, PATCH or DELETE, you may need to also let laravel know the form method you are using. Try adding "_method" property with the value "PUT", and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

My previous wrong code -

```
let data = new FormData()
data.append('message', 'AnyMessage')
```

Instead of FormData use the following `String` that works fine -

```
let data = "message=AnyMessage"
```