# Axios put method doesn't send data in vuejs application

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

When I use **axios.put** method it doesn't work and there is no data is sent to the backend, in the same time when I change the **axios.put** method to **axios.post** it works well, what is the wrong? is there any mistake in the code below?

> 1- update component:

```
<template>
  <Form @submit="update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <Field type="hidden" name="_token" :value="category.csrf" />
    <Field type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
    <div class="form-group pb-2">
      <label for="title">title</label>
      <Field
        type="text"
        class="form-control bordered"
        id="title"
        placeholder="Enter title"
        name="title"
        v-model="category.title"
        :validateOnInput="true"
        :rules="validateTitle"
      />
      <ErrorMessage name="title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group pb-2">
      <label for="photo">photo</label>
      <Field
        type="file"
        class="form-control"
        id="photo"
        name="photo"
        accept="image/jpeg ,image/jpg , image/png "
        @change="atFileChange"
        :validateOnInput="true"
      />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
  </Form>
</template>

<script>
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    Field,
    ErrorMessage,
  },
  props: ["category"],

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["updateCategory"]),
    atFileChange(event) {
      this.category.photo = event.target.files[0];
    },
    update() {
      //send form data to api
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("title", this.category.title);
      data.append("photo", this.category.photo);
      data.append(
        "_token",
        document
          .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
          .getAttribute("content")
      );
      data.append("_method", "PUT");
      const categoryId = this.category.id;
      // This is a Vuex action which commit the the update mutation
      this.updateCategory({ data: data, id: categoryId });

  },
};
</script>
```

> 2- Vuex update action method:

```
    updateCategory(context, category) {
        context.commit('updateCategory', category);
    }
```

> 3- Vuex update mutation method:

```
    updateCategory(state, category) {
        axios.put('api/categories/' + category.id + '/update', 
        category.data);
    },
```

> 4- Backend controller update method:

```
public function update(CategoryRequest $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            $category = Category::find($id);

            // 1- Start uploading file
            $path = "";
            if ($request->has('photo') && $request->photo != null && 
                getType($request->photo) !== 'string') {
                $folder = 'categories';
                $file = $request->photo;
                $file->store('/', $folder);
                $filename = $file->hashName();
                $path = 'images/' . $folder . '/' . $filename;
            }
            // End uploading file

            // 2- start Creating Slug
            $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $request->title);
            // End Creating Slug

            // 3- Start Updating category

            $category->title = $request->title;
            $category->slug = $slug;
            $category->photo = $path;
            $category->save();
            // End Updating category

            return response()->json(['message' => 'Category Updated Successfully'], 200);
         } catch (\Exception $exp) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'error on Updating Category'], 422);
       }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what error do you get in the developer console window. Can you add that as well please?

Comment: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories/4/update 422 (Unprocessable Content)

Comment: message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {title: ["The title field is required."]}}
errors: {title: ["The title field is required."]}
message: "The given data was invalid."

Comment: when I use dd($request->all()) I find no data like that =>  [ ]

Comment: Can you try running `php artisan route:list`. 

Is there a route like: `/api/categories/{id}/update`

I feel the route where you're directing the request may be wrong.

Comment: I checked the route and it is right, the problem appears when I'm using axios.put, In the case I am using axios.post the update works well

Comment: It's a known issue. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457) and [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686218/laravel-vuejs-axios-put-request-formdata-is-empty)

Comment: consider changing your `axios.put` to `axios.post`.  let your route be a post route as well

Answer (score 0):

Your api route is incorrect. It should be

```
axios.put(`/api/categories/${category.data.id}`, category.data);
```

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    Route::apiResources([
        'categories' => 'App\Http\Controllers\API\CategoryController',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working yet

Comment: What is the api route in api.php

Comment: Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories'], function() {
        Route::put('{slug}/courses/update', [CategoryCourseController::class, 'update']);
});

Comment: Your routes aren't matching. See the updated answer.

Comment: I think there are no problems with routes, I found a solution in the comments above that laravel can't work with axios.put instead I should use axios.post with _method is set to put

Comment: I don't know how many times I call axios.put(), but it's your choise. BTW, your route is wrong. We never put http::/site.com part, because routes work as relative paths. In the future, you will have a very big refactoring issue and probably some bugs. Also, put and post have different responsibilities. It's just a plain bad idea to use store (post) route for editing (put). I strongly suggest you don't do that.